# Convergence in normed linear space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

For $X$ and $Y$ normed linear spaces, let ${T_n}\rightarrow{T}$ in $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ and ${u_n}\rightarrow{u}$ in $X$. Show that ${T_n(u_n)}\rightarrow T(u)$ in $Y$.
I think in the problem there are three norms, one on $X$, one on $Y$ and the operator norm. How am I suppose to make use of these norms to show the convergence? Thanks.

Here is what I tried.
We need show $\lim{\|T_n(u_n)-T(u)\|}_y=0$,

$\|T_n(u_n)-T(u)\|\leq\|T_n(u_n)-T_n(u)\|+\|T_n(u)-T(u)\|$.
$\|T_n(u_n)-T_n(u)\|=\|(T_n(u_n-u))\|\leq\|T_n\|\|u_n-u\|$, and $\lim\|u_n-u\|=0$ since ${u_n}\rightarrow{u}$ in $X$. Thus $\|T_n(u_n)-T_n(u)\|=0$.
$\|T_n(u)-T(u)\|=\|(T_n-T)(u)\|\leq\|T_n-T\|\|u\|$, and $lim\|T_n-T\|=0$ since ${T_n}\rightarrow{T}$ in $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$. Then I got the result.

Is there anything wrong with what I did? Thanks.

Comment: You are supposed to carefully review the definitions and try to apply them yourself before you seek help, lest you will never learn anything at all.

Comment: Let me second that. If you get stuck, then report back with the specific problem.

Comment: What does it mean for $T_n \to T$? (This is a hint.)